# How can I map a Java date to DATETIME in mysql (by default its TIMESTAMP) with Hibernate annotations

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, annotations

All my db tables should have an endTime field which by default should be END_OF_TIME or something like that. I am not happy about the 2038 limitation so I want endTime to be of type DATETIME in mysql.

My Java code is:

```
@MappedSuperclass
@Inheritance(strategy=InheritanceType.TABLE_PER_CLASS)
public class BaseDBEntity {
@Id
@Column(length=36)
public String id;

@Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP) 
public Date startTime;

@Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP) 
public Date endTime;

public BaseDBEntity() {
}

}
```

I can work around by creating the table manually with an endTime field of type DATETIME, and than map the entity endTime to that column, however I would like Hibernate to generate the tables automatically - how can I do that?

Answer (score 78, accepted):

Use the `columnDefinition` attribute of the [`@Column` annotation](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/persistence/Column.html):

```
@Column(name = "startTime", columnDefinition="DATETIME")
@Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
private Date startTime;
```

And please, make your attributes private.

Comment: That works! Why is it still necessary to use the @Temporal annotation?It looks like has no additional effect.

Comment: Yes it is. The @Temporal annotation tells Hibernate if it should use a java.sql.Date or a java.sql.Timestamp to store the date read from the database. Both extend the java.util.Date class, but java.sql.Date doesn't hold any time information: only the date.

Comment: is `Date`, `java.sql.Date` or `java.util.Date`?

Comment: It has to be `java.util.Date` otherwise you will get a bunch of exceptions.

Comment: In Db i have date like  11/11/2016 3:36:50 PM after using above solution i am getting   "created_on": "2016-11-11", but i want complete date and time both.. and in my desired format... any help please !!!

Comment: I think his attributes should be "protected", since they are used in an inherited class.